# Where is the wrong step? Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus

Since $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$ we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} = -\ln|1-x|$$

Therefore, for $x \neq 0$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n+1} = \dfrac{-\ln|1-x|}{x^2}$$ and therefore for $x \neq 0$ we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}  = \int_{0}^{x}
\dfrac{-\ln|1-t|}{t^2} dt$$ Using integration by parts $\Big(V = -ln(1-t), V' = \dfrac{1}{1-t}, U' = \dfrac{1}{t^2}, U = -\dfrac{1}{t}\Big)$ we get this is equal to: $$\dfrac{ln|1-t|}{t}\Bigg|^x_0  +\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{t(1-t)}dt$$ But this integral does not converge... Why is this wrong?

Comment: Why are you integrating from $0$?

Comment: @Arthur but if we define f(x) = the required sum, then f'(x) = sum of x^{n-1}/(n+1) which is equal as i proved to -ln(1-x)/x^2. therefore, since the integral from 0 to x of f'(x) is equal to f(x)-f(0) = f(x), we get that what i did is true

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: You actually have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n+1} = \frac{-x-\ln(1-x)}{x^2}$$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Right. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have dropped out the term $n=0.$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\color{red}{\neq }\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Rather, you should get: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{n+1} = \frac{-x-\ln(1-x)}{x^2}$$

It's easier to write $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n+1}$$

So if $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$ then this is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}=f(x)-\frac{f(x)-x}{x}$$

But we know that $f(x)=-\log(1-x)$, so we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}=\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)\log(1-x) + 1$$

When $x\to 0$ the right hand side converges to $0.$

Also, as $x\to 1^-$ we get $(1-x)\log(1-x)\to 0$ so the right side converges to $1$, and the sum when $x=1$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^n \frac{1}{n(n+1)} 
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)}\\
&=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}+1\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}+1\\
&= 1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \log(1-x)
\end{align}$

Comment: @ who A detailed calculation is worth a downvote?

Comment: I apologize, I thought that I had seen a mistake in your work but I was incorrect.

Comment: Detecting a supposed error might be worth a comment first ;-)

Comment: You're right, I apologize.