# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form

I have come across the series$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n(n+1)}, \quad|a|<1$$
in an intermediate step while solving a problem.
I wonder if there is a closed form for it?
I could only observe that it can be written as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$, but the usual telescoping trick doesn't work here.
I am unaware of usable techniques. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Integrate $\sum_1^{\infty} a^{n-1}$ twice and divide by $a$.

Comment: Wow it worked thank you very much!

Comment: Use the formula searching tool approach0.xyz, you will find at once answers such as this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210006

Comment: This becomes [popular](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4103029) these days...